# Restrict the Subscribers of certain whitelist IPs to connect to Topic in google pub sub

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

How can we restrict the subscribers of certain whitelist ips have the access to the Topic in google pub sub?

Some other program which have the topic name is reading messages from the Topic, so we want to know how can we restrict the access to the Topic messages.

Comment: Access to topics and subscriptions can be controlled through Google Cloud Platform IAM permissions (roles and groups).  I haven't heard any stories where the the "IP address" of the client is used as an access discriminator.  Can you partition those clients that need access from those that don't by their identities?

Answer (score 0):

One of Google recommendation is "don't trust the network". And there are right. Prefer the service account identity.

However, some customers, or use cases, required to rely on network. That's why [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) exists, but it's only for VMs/loadbalancer.

Sorry, you can't directly. The not recommended solution could be to set up a proxy on a VM to filter this. Or to offer a HTTP endpoint on a VM which simply get the message and publish it to PubSub.

It's not recommended because you are doing what google want to avoid (trust the network) and you have to manage yourself the scalability and the high availability.

Comment: Yes we are going with Proxy server - limiting the access in proxy before reaching the pubsub server.